# check alternation maxima minima in matlab

Tags: matlab, alternation, minima

I have written an algorithm that finds the local maxima and minima in a signal.

```
[id_max, id_min] = find_max_min(signal);
```

I would like now to check:
if the alterantion of maxima and minima is respected

```
i.e. id_max(1)<id_min(1)<id_max(2)<id_min(2)<... 
we could start with a minimum..this is not known
```

Suppose that:

```
 id_max = [1 3 5 7 10 14 20];

 id_min = [2 4 6 8 16 19];
```

I would like to have 2 vectors `missing_max` `missing_min` indicating the location of the missing maxima and minima.

A missing maximum (minimum) occours when between two consecutive minima (maxima) in `id_min (id_max)` there is not a maximum (minimum).

In this example a maximum is missing in the 7th position of id_max because in id_min there are two consecutive values (16 19) without a maximum between.

Then we have

```
missing_max = [7]

missing_min = [5]
```

since

```
id_max = [1 3 5 7 10 14 X 20];
```

`id_min = [2 4 6 8 X 16 19];` (with X I marked the missing values)

If the alternation is correct the vectors should be empty. Can you suggest an efficient way to do that without for loops?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the IDs guaranteed to have integer values?

Comment: yes they are integers

Comment: Soon I'll give an answer. However: between the 4th = 8 and the 5th = 16 position in minima there are maxima, 10 and 14. `missing_min` should be `[6]`, don't you agree?

Comment: yes I agree, I edited the question

Comment: sorry, actually no I don't agree because a minimum is missing in the 5th position because there are 2 consecutive maxima in 5th and 6th position

Comment: Oh, that changes a bit the problem... first of all, you need to guarantee that the id vectors are sorted, otherwise "position" would mean nothing. Can you guarantee that?

Comment: yes. Sorry if I was not clear

Comment: Okay, just to clarify the definition, I'd like to have one more example: suppose `id_min=[2 4 6 8 10]` and `id_max=[12 14]`. What would be `missing_max` and `missing_mim`

Comment: it should be missin_min = [6] and missing_max = [1 2 3 4]

Comment: But there are no 3rd and 4th position in `id_max`, and no 6th position in `id_min`, so "a value missing between k-1 and k position" does not work. Could you elaborate on how you got to those values?

Comment: I sort the maxima and the minima in an unique array taking in consideration that a maximum should be between 2 minima and vice versa. so it will be [2,?,4,?,6,?,8,?,10,12,?,14] in this case the odd positions are the minima (we start with a minimum) and the even ones the maxima. I divided by 2 to get the indeces.

Comment: There you go. You just said the algorithm you were looking for. :-)

Comment: mmm not sure I am able to implement this... because I don't know how long should be this sorted vector...on paper I can add the question marks where I think it s necessary...

Comment: New code. Not so different from the initial one... but still. As I said in the post, there's a little teaser embedded into the script: you either fix it, or write a really nice, well-explained definition of `missing_max` and `missing_in` (then I'll fix it). What do you say? :-)

Comment: I say that I edited the question and did my best :)

Comment: Fixed the code and added explanation of the bug. Hope it will work well for what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Here's a script that you can adapt to a function if you want:</s>

```
    id_max = [1 3 5 7 10 14 20];
    id_min = [2 4 6 8 16 19];

    % Group all values, codify extremity (1-max, 0-min), and position
    id_all   = [          id_max,              id_min  ];
    code_all = [ones(size(id_max)), zeros(size(id_min))];
    posn_all = [  1:numel(id_max),     1:numel(id_min) ];

    % Reshuffle the codes and positions according to sorted IDs of min/max
    [~, ix]  = sort(id_all);
    code_all = code_all(ix);
    posn_all = posn_all(ix);

    % Find adjacent IDs that have the same code, i.e. code diff = 0
    code_diff = (diff(code_all)==0);

    % Get the indices of same-code neighbors, and their original positions
    ix_missing_min = find([code_diff,false] & (code_all==1));
    ix_missing_max = find([code_diff,false] & (code_all==0));

    missing_min    = posn_all(ix_missing_min+1);
    missing_max    = posn_all(ix_missing_max+1);
```

**Caveats on IDs:**

1. Make sure your `id_min` and `id_max` are rows (even if empty);
2. Make sure that at least one of them is not empty;
3. While they need not to be sorted, their values must be unique (within the IDs and across).

**Later edit:**

New version of the code, based on new explanations about the definition:

```
    id_max = [1 3 5 7 10 14 20];
    id_min = [2 4 6 8 16 19];
    %id_max = [12 14]
    %id_min = [2 4 6 8 10];

    id_min_ext = [-Inf, id_min];
    id_max_ext = [-Inf, id_max];

    % Group all values, and codify their extremity (1-max, 0-min), and position
    id_all   = [          id_max_ext,              id_min_ext  ];
    code_all = [ones(size(id_max_ext)), zeros(size(id_min_ext))];
    posn_all = [  0:numel(id_max),         0:numel(id_min)     ];

    % Reshuffle the codes and position according to sorted positions of min/max
    [~, ix] = sort(id_all);
    code_all = code_all(ix);
    posn_all = posn_all(ix);

    % Find adjacent IDs that have the same code, i.e. code diff = 0
    code_diff = (diff(code_all)==0);

    % Get the indices of same-code neighbours, and their original positions
    ix_missing_min = find([code_diff,false] & (code_all==1));
    ix_missing_max = find([code_diff,false] & (code_all==0));

    missing_min    = unique(posn_all(ix_missing_min-1))+1;
    missing_max    = unique(posn_all(ix_missing_max-1))+1;
```

<s>However, the code contains a subtle bug. The bug will be removed by either the person that asked the question, or by me after he/she improves the question in such a way that is really clear what's asked for. :-)</s> Due the fact that we have 2 virtual extremums (one max and one min, at ID = −∞) is possible that the first missing extremum will be marked twice: once at −∞ and once at the first element of the ID list. `unique()` will take care of that (though is too much of a function call to check if the first 2 elements of an array have the same value)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this is not what I was looking for...I edited my question...I did a bit of confusion before..